# Is there any dependency between MCU and X-Men films?

Tags: marvel, movie, marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men, suggested-order

Is there any need to have watched any MCU films in order to watch any of the 7 X-Men films (2000-2014)?

On one hand, they are all Marvel universe based and obviously all share interconnected continuity and storylines in the comics.

On another hand, IIRC, they are different movie studios with incompatible rights, so presumably the cinematic canon is 100% disjoint.

Comment: If you don't know the rights background, then watching *Age of Ultron* / *Days of Future Past* might confuse you ("Wait, why is Quicksilver so young in the 60s?"), but otherwise they *should* be separate

Comment: @JasonBaker - I just know that X-Men rights belong to 20thCenturyFox and that is a source of some discontent.

Comment: Basically Marvel is allowed to use Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch as long as they're not called mutants. There's a question somewhere on here about that. But that's the only intersection I can think of

Comment: @RogueJedi - I would like to see a bit more authoritative answer, but I suppose the existing one is the best possible. I'll accept for now, but i'd love to see something more cited from Marvel re: lack of dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no dependency. The two franchises are completely separate and neither impacts the other in any way. There is no need to watch any of one to understand the other.

[The MCU takes place in Earth-199999 and the XCU takes place in Earth-10005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(Marvel_Comics)), so canonically, they both take place in totally separate universes.

However, there are two characters whose rights [are owned by both companies](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/74172/20150805/your-guide-to-which-movie-studios-own-marvel-characters.htm), Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver. Quicksilver has had unrelated appearances in both universes, but Scarlet Witch has so-far only appeared in the MCU.

Comment: Why are there so many Earth-1xxxxxx in the Marvel Universe...?